# Laravel datatables draw parameter always 0

Tags: laravel, datatables

In my Laravel application, I'm using Yarja datatables. Local it works perfectly. On the test server, it works also perfect. But on the customer server, paginate, sort and search doesn't work. I found out that the request contains a `draw` var and also the response.

This var is counted from 1 up. On the test server the draw-var in request is always the same like in the response. But on the customer server, the draw-var int the request is counted correctly, but in the response the draw-var is always 0.

Request:

[image]

Response:

[image]

What can be the error? I have no idea where I have to search.

Comment: You posted pictures only; what about some code? :); Most likely local / test environment has different web server configuration or software so I'd look there first. Do you control client's web server or not?

Comment: Which code is the most helpful?

Comment: The server admin seted up both serves. So he compared and all settings are the same.

Comment: The one you suspect the most, either controller and method which handles the request. Route definition may be useful. And of course server setup on clients server; maybe .htaccess if used or vhost configuration or nginx specific configuration etc. At that point its not really a SO question but [SF question](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I think problem is in config or in bad installation. First of all, U must check the 
datatable versions on loc/test/prod; second: check package settings. We can`t help without any data

Comment: First i deployed it with `composer install`, `npm install` and `npm run dev`. Then i tried to copy the complete code with node_modules and vendor to the customer server. No changes